# Is a planet's southern hemisphere necessarily warmer than the north?

Tags: science-based, planets, climate

Epic fantasies typically depict northern areas as cold and southern areas as relatively warm. Is this just to play into reader expectations since that's the way it is on Earth, or is there a scientific reason that a planet's northern hemisphere will tend to be cooler?

Comment: What? Surely you mean Equatorial vs Arctic

Comment: Earth's Southern Hemisphere is colder than the Northern.

Comment: That's not the way it is on earth. Just most of the "deep south" is ocean so we end up with the idea that the south is all hot (plus there's a lot of north hemisphere thinking going on)

Comment: It's because [90% of the population lives in the northern hemisphere](http://www.businessinsider.com/90-of-people-live-in-the-northern-hemisphere-2012-5). Most epic fantasies are written by people in the northern hemisphere where south is warmer and north is cooler.

Comment: I see I fell for a common trope. Sorry for the stupid question.

Comment: @Dio not stupid at all.  We all learn new things here.  Welcome the site.

Comment: @Dio [No such thing as a stupid question](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_such_thing_as_a_stupid_question).

Comment: @Dio There is a [trope page for it](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NorthIsColdSouthIsHot). It's a good question.

Comment: You could place Antarctica on top and call it the north. We have it in the south now but it has not always been a convention.

Comment: I think most fantasy is simply set in the Northern hemisphere (where the author and most readers live), and the reader never finds out what the temperature is in the Southern Hemisphere, for much the same reason medieval people didn't know the temeprature in Australia - it's off the map of the known world.

Comment: @Richard Tingle: Also has a lot to do with the shape of land in the southern hemisphere.  Other than the very tip of South America (which is quite narrow), all the continuous land ends in temperate latitudes, if not sooner.  (Antarctica is of course a long sail away.)  Whereas in the nothern hemisphere, you can easily drive (or ride horses/reindeer/dog sleds if that's your tech level) well north of the Arctic Circle.

Comment: @Vincent that is by far the best explanation so far. Simple and clear. Post it as an answer and I'll give it 50% of my rep in bounty.

Comment: I know this question may have been answered already, and of course it depends on the high fantasy in question, but I've always figured that if we are IN a high fantasy setting, it's likely the characters would have very little experience with the entirety of the breadth and depth of their planet; that is to say, it may be hot if you go towards the equator, but the character probably hasn't ventured far enough south of the equator for it to start getting cold again.

Comment: I am *very* glad you asked this question.  Few people realize how planetary climate actually works, and it's good to have this question as a searchable bit of internet knowledge for future folks.  +1 m8.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

No, there's no scientific reason to why a given latitude to the south of the average planet should be any different in average temperature to the same latitude north.

Perhaps this is slightly reinforced by the fact that on Earth there happens to be a lower ratio of land to sea in the southern hemisphere than in the northern hemisphere. Antarctica is surrounded by a vast ocean; there's no one living as close to the south pole as, say, northern Russia or Greenland is to the north pole.

Basically, the perception arises because most SF and fantasy writers come from countries in the northern hemisphere, so from their home town things get colder if you go north and hotter if you go south.

Comment: And this carries over to different kinds of "geographical reflexes" so to speak. In Poland we have sea to the north and mountains to the south and if I am to come up with a world for, let's say, an RPG campaign I automatically want to keep it similar.

Comment: As well most "planet's" I've seen formed follow Earth's structure pretty close: ie most land mass in northern hemisphere ...vaguely North American shaped contient as the "main" one .. etc.

Answer (score 25):

## Nope

Most of the [Earth's current population lives in the northern hemisphere](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&espv=2&q=what%20percentage%20of%20people%20live%20in%20the%20northern%20hemisphere&spell=1&sa=X&ei=dsJHVfaeEsXwoATqiYHoCg&ved=0CBsQvwUoAA&biw=1252&bih=778&safe=high). That means 88% of people think going north from the current position results in a colder climate.

Why has this translated into fantasy? My only guess is that the authors of those fantasies are simply so used to equating north with cold, that it just carried over. There are exceptions to this, of course.

Answer (score 10):

Building on the excellent answers others have given concerning the fact that most fantasy has been written from the Northern Hemispherical perspective (and hence via N-S as an increasing temperature axis), there are actually differences between hemispheres which you could build in to your world. You could also make them more extreme.

First, the earth is nearest to the Sun (perihelion) in early January (4th January in 2015). Since the earth is also moving faster around the Sun at that point this means that:

- the Northern hemisphere gets more solar radiation in its Winter than the Southern gets in its Winter
- Norther Winters are a little shorter and hence their Summers are a little longer than in the Southern hemisphere

The earth's orbit is very close to being a circle (eccentricity 0.0167) so these effects are not that large. It took a long time before ancient astronomers realised that there was anything going on at all. A more eccentric orbit could make these things rather different.

The date of perihelion also changes (because of the precession of the apsides) very slowly — again, that is something that could be different in an artificial world.

However, another bigger effect means that, counter-intuitively, the earth is actually warmer when it is further from the Sun (at aphelion) because that is when the Southern hemisphere (mostly ocean) gets the Sun's radiation rather than perihelion when the Northern hemisphere gets it. There are two neat explanations of this here:

- [Today I Found Out: The Earth is Hottest When It Is Furthest From the Sun On Its Orbit, Not When It Is Closest](http://www.todayifoundout.com/index.php/2011/12/the-earth-is-hottest-when-it-is-furthest-from-the-sun-on-its-orbit-not-when-it-is-closest/)
- [Aphelion: shouldn't earth be at its coldest today?](http://www.bbc.co.uk/blogs/legacy/23degrees/2011/07/aphelion_our_sun_isnt_right_in.html)

So you could build a world with a different distribution of continents to change these effects as well.

Comment: And since that isn't complicated enough, ocean currents, like the [Gulf Stream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gulf_Stream) can have a significant influence on local climate as well.

Answer (score 6):

Earth's southern hemisphere isn't warmer than the northern. The closer you get to the north/south poles, the colder it gets, as those areas get less sunlight than other areas, like the equator. I'm guessing the 'epic fantasy' you're referencing is A Song of Ice and Fire. The weather there is funky and fickle, and no one is certain why it is. There are theories, like the planet this world is on has a wacky axis, or that it isn't even on a planet. You can incorporate some of those ideas into your story.

Comment: Of course if all of westeros is in the northern hemisphere it all makes sense

Comment: Faerûn or Middle Earth are arguably better examples of an epic fantasy land that fits this description.

Comment: @Samuel: But Middle Earth explicitly is our own world in a previous age, and though "...the shape of all lands has been changed; but the regions in which Hobbits then lived were doubtless the same as those in which they still linger: the North-West of the Old World, East of the Sea." (From the Prologue to The Fellowship of the Ring.)

Comment: @jamesqf I'm not sure if or how your statement agrees with, disagrees with, or adds to my own. Middle-earth, regardless of relation to our Earth, was an epic fantasy land with a cold north and warm south. Right?

Comment: The world of Robert Jordan's Wheel of Time also follows this pattern (though granted it is heavily imitative of Tolkien), with freezing northern borderlands and something unmapped (The Blight vs The Land of Always Winter) beyond.

Comment: @Samuel: I'm saying that Middle Earth had to have the same cold north/warm south as our Earth because it is our Earth, so it's not a good example to use for the Northern Hemisphere prejudice.  And note that people have done actual climate models for Middle Earth: http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/climate-scientist-takes-on-tolkiens-middle-earth/

Comment: @jamesqf Our Earth *doesn't* have a cold north/warm south. It's precisely a northern hemisphere prejudice that leads to the belief.

Answer (score 5):

Why do we tend to think of south as hot?  This may have something to do with it:

[image]

Comment: Nice graph.  Note that the straight part of the US-Canadian border is at 49 degrees north, so all the land in the southern hemisphere (other than Antarctica and a few islands) is closer to the equator than the continental US.

Comment: That graph is wonky. Near the South Pole it should be 100 percent land, not 0.  In the North, near the pole should be 0, land, but there's sure more than 12 percent coverage where Siberia and North America ring the Arctic Ocean.

Comment: @Oldcat I suspect that this is due to "corrected for circumference", whatever that may be.

Comment: @Oldcat In particular, the graph claims that no latitude has more than about 13% land. If that were the case, the whole world couldn't have more than 13% land. But it does.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Correct: because the circumference of the earth at 90&deg;S is zero, the area of land there is zero, despite 100% of that latitude being covered by land.
Think of it this way: "All of the land in the southern hemisphere is in dark green.  All of the land in the northern hemisphere is in light green.  The distribution of that land across latitude is shown to compare the absolute latitude of land in the north vs the south."
Two facts jump out at us:
+ most of the land is in the northern hemisphere
+ land in the southern hemisphere is huddled closer to the equator

Comment: @David Richerby:  I may have some tweaking to do, but your conclusion doesn't follow from your initial statement.  Remember that this is the contribution of a given band of latitude toward the global total: if any band had 100%, the rest would all have to be zero.  But still, I'm not happy with this graph.  I'll hit it after work tonight.
Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: Ohhhh. You need to explain that graph a lot better, and it needs redrawing, too. It should be a bar graph, not a line graph, because it's not displaying a continuous quantity. (The line is misleading as it makes the viewer think they can read off the value at, say, latitude 6.3 but they can't.) Actually, I don't understand your graph at all. What does "corrected for circumference" mean? What does "contribution of %land vs water per latitude band towards 100% mean"? Towards 100% of what? If it's a contribution towards 100%, then shouldn't all the datapoints of each colour add up to 100? etc.

Comment: Right now, I'm not convinced that the quantity you're graphing has any actual meaning.

Comment: Major edit; replacing the graph.

Comment: @Haakon Dahl: The original graph was much, much clearer.

Comment: @jamesqf: Thank you , but it was also wrong.  First, I had misread a scalar as a percentage for my source data (which I was just eyeballing for values), and off the wrong scale to boot, leading me to apply an unneeded "correction" that was an error.  Second, while I like the appearance of the first graph, David Richerby is correct that a bar graph is better than a line  graph for discrete values.  Finally, a graph which needs excessive explanation is not doing its job, and I despair of explaining a stacked bar graph here.
So while I rather liked the first graph, it had to go.  But thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The solar exposure difference between the northern and southern hemisphere is determined by the planet's spin axis and the planets equator (perpendicular to the spin axis), as in this picture:

### [image: Equator]

So you could potentially have a gravitationally locked planet (like Mercury) with a spin axis of -90' (like Uranus) and its northern hemisphere exposed to the system's star all year long and scorched, and the southern hemisphere plunged in the dark and blistering cold, with the only life possible being in a ring 5 degrees below the equator in the southern hemisphere. In reality such a planet would probably not be habitable because of insane weather and thermal stress constantly cracking the surface due to the enormous temperature delta between both hemispheres.

I think it's just easier to say north is colder than south from a northern hemisphere point of view, almost metaphorically, especially in science fiction.

Comment: There are some really important details missing here (e.g. how do you get "the northern hemisphere exposed to the system's star all year long") which lead you to make statements that are exactly backwards ("tidal forces constantly cracking the surface").

Comment: Also let's not forget this isn't Astronomy, the question was asked from a fiction point of view. I would like to hear what makes you think my statements are backwards and my details "missing". If you will downvote an answer, I would at least expect you to provide a better one. Uranus has in fact an axis tilt of 97 degrees, so you don't have to look far for examples.

Comment: Tidal forces are constant when you're either gravitationally locked or have a pole facing what you're orbiting.  (You can't have both due to conservation of rotational momentum.)  So in the scenario you state, tidal forces would be mild (due to orbital eccentricity).  But the scenario is not physically possible, as far as I can tell from the details you've given.

Answer (score -1):

For **conventional** planets it's completely wrong that the southern hemisphere "is colder".

When you are in one hemisphere **or the other**,

it gets warmer **as you move towards the equator**.

So, ***IF*** you are in the ***Northern hemisphere***, it gets warmer **as you move South**.

So, ***IF*** you are in the ***Southern hemisphere***, it gets warmer **as you move North**.

Comment: *"when you are in one hemisphere **or the other**, it gets colder **as you move towards the equator**."* So Morocco is colder than Finland? Good to know. I *think* you meant to write that it gets *warmer* as you move toward the equator (but I'm not going to unilaterally make such an edit to an answer that already has upvotes). Which of course doesn't *necessarily* work *either;* compare Uranus for an extreme example of what [a whacky axial tilt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uranus#Axial_tilt) can do. The reason why the Uranian equator is less cold than the poles is unknown.

Comment: As Michael says. The claims here are wrong and you have received down votes for that; correct the mistakes and they may be retracted.

Comment: No, it doesn't, to be brutally honest. The science here is still wrong and I don't what any typo has to do with it.

Comment: You raise a very good point with some social implications (so I'm not surprised your answer was downvoted;)  Beyond the social implications, I suspect part of the reason is that there is more real estate in the colder parts of the Northern hemisphere than the Southern.